# Action of translation operator on ket in momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

I know how translation operator $T(a)$ acts on ket in position representation and changes it from $|x>$ to $|x+a>$. I want to know how will $T(a)$ act on a ket in momentum representation. I read somewhere it takes an exponential form but I am not able to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation opertor is $T_a= \exp\{- a\partial_x\}= \exp\{-ia\hat p\}$ acts on a momentum eigenstate $|p\rangle$ by
$$
T_a  |p\rangle= e^{-iap}|p\rangle, \quad \langle p|T_a= e^{iap}\langle p|
$$
and hence on a momentum space wavefunction $f(p)=\langle p  |\psi\rangle$ as
$$
\langle p|T_a |\psi\rangle= e^{iap} \langle p|\psi\rangle
$$